# Change the default terminal used by Visual Studio (Mac)

Tags: c#, terminal, visual-studio-mac

What I want is to use my .zsh shell instead of the default (mac) terminal when building/running my compiled C# code. Is there a way I achieve this with the newly released Visual Studio for mac?

**Note:** I am referring to Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently not possible. Microsoft just re-branded the Xamarin studio into visual studio for mac. And the default terminal was hard-coded into it. There were multiple feature request for numerous terminals ([this one for example](https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-platform-suggestions/suggestions/9824532-run-console-application-in-iterm2)).
"Run on external console" (with default terminal) is the only option in this regard.

Comment: Thanks mate. Too bad they haven't gotten around to it yet -- but hopefully it will be here soon.